# Retrofit2 and baseurl in GitLap

Tags: retrofit2, gitlab-api

I am trying to learn retrofit2 by showing my project's **GitLab** name into recyclerView . but I can not find what is exactly what to do!!!
according gitlab [wiki](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#authentication) I found private-tokens and [list](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#list-user-projects) of projrct.

this is my baseUrl and I create a builder:

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=xxxxxx")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
```

and this is my endpoint:

```
@GET("/users/:{userid}/projects")
Call<List<GitLabRepo>> reposForUser(@Path("userid") int user);
```

my GitLabRepo pojo class:

```
class GitLabRepo {

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}
```

after running I got this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sayres.createandroidclient/com.example.sayres.createandroidclient.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=rjezfrSUTn3fcugxLujm/
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=xxxxxx/
                                                 at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:513)
                                                 at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:456)
                                                 at com.example.sayres.createandroidclient.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
```

I know my problem is related to baseUrl but what is correct `gitLab BaseUrl`?
I want just show my **project name** into list at recycelerview list.

******************Edit******************
I use of poster :

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=******/users/:******/projects
```

And I got :

```
{
"message": "401 Unauthorized"
}
```

I see into `Status codes` at [gitlab wiki](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#authentication) and wrote there:

```
401 Unauthorized    The user is not authenticated, a valid user token is necessary.
```

but I have added **Private Tokens** .

Answer (score 0):

remove the forward slash '/' from get i.e,change your code like this

```
@GET("users/:{userid}/projects/")
Call<List<GitLabRepo>> reposForUser(@Path("userid") int user);
```

and add '/' in your endpoint like this

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=xxxxxx/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
```

Comment: I do your suggestion but I still got above error:`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=xxxxxxxx/`

Comment: have you added / at the end of base url after token,then add add  '/' it after projects also like this users/:{userid}/projects/

Comment: yes. `.baseUrl("https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=xxxx/")`

Comment: then add add '/'  after projects also like this users/:{userid}/projects/

Comment: maybe because of an unauthorized token, are you sure the value of private_token that you are passing is correct,you will have to use a valid  token obtained from gitlab api

Comment: yes, I have copied this token from my account setting into my gitlab profile.

Comment: try removing the ':' from @GET("users/:{userid}/projects/")

Comment: I removed and I tested in poster :`https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=xxxxxx` and I got json response. not mine json project. but when I run this link as a base url at android studio I got `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=xxxxx`